# Commit Count in solr

Tags: apache, solr

How can i get the commit count?
Because if the mergefactor=10 then at the 10th time of the commit merge happen(where the docid get changed)...
So is there any way to get commit counts?...
Plese help me....

Advance thanks...

Comment: Whenever the merge happens the Docid is changing. In my application i am creating Hash map with Docid.For creating that hashmap i m having a function. So can any one tell me when will the merge happen. so that i can recreate my hash map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a commit count from the stats page, i.e. admin/stats.jsp#update